# Test equivalence of non-nested models

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, regression, model-selection

Let's say $y$ is a linear function of $x$ and a dummy $d$. My hypothesis is that $d$ itself is like a hedonistic index of a vector of other variables, $Z$. I have support for this in a $MANOVA$ of $Z$ (i.e. $z_1$, $z_2$, ..., $z_n$) on $d$. Is there any way to test the *equivalence* of these two models:

Model 1: $y = b_0 + b_1 \cdot x + b_2\cdot d + e_1$

Model 2: $y = g_0 + Z\cdot G + e_2$

where $G$ is the column vector of parameters.

Answer (score 8):

To begin with you have to define the **equivalence** concept. One may think that two models are equivalent when they do produce almost the same *forecasting accuracy* (this one would be relevant for time series and panel data), another one could be interested in if *the fits from the model are close*. The former is the object for different cross-validation (jack-knife usually or some out-of-sample tests, Rob's `accuracy()` do this nicely), the latter goes for the minimization of some information criterion.

In microeconometrics the choice is [$BIC$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_information_criterion), though you may also consider [$AIC$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion) if you are working with small sample sizes. Note, that the choice based on minimization of information criterion is also relevant for nested models.

A nice discussion is given in must-have-it [book](http://books.google.ru/books?id=Zf0gCwxC9ocC&pg=PA278&lpg=PA278&dq=information+criteria+non-nested+models&source=bl&ots=CY24qI6KtY&sig=_kPXnMgkG3g-X3wQaF2oGJ955X8&hl=ru&ei=qbKFTf23DJDAswby69GQAw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=10&ved=0CGAQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Cameron and Trivedi (Chapter 8.5 provides excellent review of the methods), more specific theoretical details are found in Hong and Preston [here](http://www.stanford.edu/~doubleh/eco273B/nonnestmsc.pdf).

Roughly speaking, choosing from two models the more parsimonious (having less parameters to estimate, therefore more degrees of freedom) will be suggested as preferable. An information criterion introduces a special penalty function that restricts the inclusion of additional explanatory variables into linear model conceptually similar to the restrictions introduced by adjusted $R^2$.

However you may not be just interested in choosing the model that minimizes selected information criterion. Equivalence concept implies that some *test statistic* should be formulated. Therefore you may go for likelihood ratio tests either Cox or Voung $LR$ tests, Davidson-MacKinnon $J$ test.

Finally, according to the tags, you may be just interested in `R` functions:

```
library(lmtest)
coxtest(fit1, fit2)
jtest(fit1, fit2)
```

Where `fit1` and `fit2` are two non-nested fitted linear regression models, `coxtest` is the Cox $LR$ test, and `jtest` Davidson-MacKinnon $J$ test.

Comment: Thanks, Dmitrij. If I understand correctly, both coxtest and jtest are essentially modified nested tests. Step1: Run the model with the combined pool of regressors from model1 and model2. Step2: Test each of model1 and model2 separately as subsets of the "supermodel". Am I right?  Also, on the note of IC measures, is there any way to statistically compare the AIC/BIC differences between models 1 and 2? Note: I am NOT trying to pick the "best" model, but you are right in that I am essentially trying test whether two models have the same fits.

Comment: @user, you do not need to add to a supermodel anything, just supply `jtest` or `coxtest` with non-nested fits from Step1. Information criterion for non-nested will be a nice guide to what model is more statistically suitable (parsimonious), but for the hypothesis testing I would just go for any $LR$ (actually the log likelihood is a part of any info-criterion) tests myself. Conclusions will be somewhat close, but since there are two deterministically given penalty functions it is a bit tricky to compare them statistically.