# How to fit a specific model to some data

Tags: r, regression, modeling

I have two dependent variables, DV1 and DV2, and one independent variable IV.  I want to ascertain if the fitted model between DV1 and IV explains the relationship between DV2 and IV well or not.

First I am fitting two separate models thus:

```
ModelA<-lm(DV1~IV)
ModelB<-lm(DV2~IV)
```

I then want to extract the fitted slope from Model A, and fit it to the relationship of DV2~IV.  I'm then going to extract the residuals from this new fitted relationship, and compare them with the residuals from Model B.

In order to do this, I need to be able to specify the slope that is fitted to the relationship between DV2 and IV, but I don't know how to do so.  I realise this is probably very simple!  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think what you mean is exactly what Cox test does -- compare two non nested models. Take a look at [this](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/lmtest/docs/coxtest) manual entry for the `coxtest` function from the R package `lmtest`.

See also [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8513/test-equivalence-of-non-nested-models) question.

As for a linear fit with a pre-specified offset. Say, x is your predictor, y is your response, and a is a predefined coefficient (slope). Fit the model as follows:

```
lm( y - a*x ~ 1 )
```

That way, you will only be estimating the intercept term. Another way that will yield the same results:

```
lm( y ~ 1 + offset( a * x ) )
```

Comment: I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think a cox test requires that the dependent variable in both cases is the same, so I don't know if this is what I want here?