# What are some statistical methods to compare two non-nested regression models?

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood, aic

For example, if you want to model the price of a particular product across different countries, and you do not know if you should use the average total earning per household or average earning per person, of course along with a lot of other variables, is there any formal statistical procedure to choose between the two, apart from AIC and BIC? It does not make much sense to include both as they are highly correlated.

It would be great if this can be applied to non-linear regression but if not possible, some insights on linear case are also greatly appreciated!

Comment: Would you like to clarify if http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8557/testing-the-difference-in-aic-of-two-non-nested-models?rq=1 answers your question?

Comment: sorry I am looking for methods apart from AIC or BIC. It does not even have to be rigorous -- some ad-hoc method would be useful too

Comment: Try this Q&A then http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8513/test-equivalence-of-non-nested-models/8519#8519 which is linked from the one I first mentioned.